# Render Large Images in MFC

Tags: image, winapi, mfc

I am trying to render large images (10K x 10K) inside a CView in MFC. The performance with GdiPlus is really slow (0.5 fps to be precise). Is there any free or commercial library which I could use for the purpose?

DirectX Rendering Code

```
float halfWidth = m_CurWidth/2.0;
float halfHeight = m_CurHeight/2.0;

D3DXMATRIX P;
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&P, (float)rect.Width(), (float)rect.Height(), -10, 10);
m_pDevice3D->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &P);

float cornerX = m_Left;
float cornerY = -m_Top;

VERTEX g_vVertices[4];
{
    g_vVertices[0] = VERTEX(cornerX + (-1.0f * halfWidth), cornerY + (1.0f * halfHeight), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    g_vVertices[1] = VERTEX(cornerX + (1.0f * halfWidth), cornerY + (1.0f * halfHeight), 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    g_vVertices[2] = VERTEX(cornerX + (-1.0f * halfWidth), cornerY + (-1.0f * halfHeight), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    g_vVertices[3] = VERTEX(cornerX + (1.0f * halfWidth), cornerY + (-1.0f * halfHeight), 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
};

 void * pVertices;
 m_pVB->Lock( 0, sizeof(pVertices), (void**)&pVertices, 0 );
 memcpy( pVertices, g_vVertices, sizeof(g_vVertices));
 m_pVB->Unlock();

if(m_pDevice3D){
    m_pDevice3D->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
        0xffffffff, 1.0f, 0);
    m_pDevice3D->BeginScene();
    m_pDevice3D->SetFVF(D3DFVF_VERTEX);
    m_pDevice3D->SetStreamSource(0, m_pVB, 0, sizeof(VERTEX));
    // Draw primitives using presently enabled texture.
    m_pDevice3D->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
    m_pDevice3D->EndScene();
    m_pDevice3D->Present(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to have all the pixels rendered at once? You could use scroll view instead and render only the portion inside the scroll area. However, you are right that GDIPlus is slow. You can use GDI's BitBlt directly for the purpose.

Comment: I actually need to allow zoom in/out on image as well so rendering a segment isn't an option. I also tried rendering with Direct3D but the quality was really off!

Comment: I see. You can do zooming with StretchBlt but it won't be too fast too. Can you show the DirectX code ?

Comment: You can add m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR); and m_pDevice3D->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_LINEAR); to see if there is an improvement in the quality. Also subtract 0.5f from each corner with texture coord 0, like this: cornerX + (-1.0f * halfWidth) - 0.5f; and add 0.5f to the corners with texture coord 1 like this: cornerY + (-1.0f * halfHeight) + 0.5f

Comment: I am already using the specified filters. But I don't understand the purpose of +-0.5 in mapping.

Comment: This is the so called Half Pixel Offset: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690(v=vs.85).aspx; http://www.asawicki.info/news_1516_half-pixel_offset_in_directx_11.html; http://aras-p.info/blog/2016/04/08/solving-dx9-half-pixel-offset/; http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It didn't help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140079/discussion-between-muhammad-tauseef-and-vuvirt).

Comment: [Leadtools](https://www.leadtools.com/)

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef do you still need help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can suggest something